# Connect printer to computers on different networks using VPN tunnel?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, printer

I have two internet providers, Verizon and Comcast and different computers connected to each one. My PC is plugged into directly to the FiOS interface (no router at all) and my Comcast connection is connected to an Airport Express Extreme which then has two different computers connected to two of its three ports. The Airport has one unused port currently. This is the way it is now:

[image: topology current]

What I want to do is add a shared printer. I happen to have a "VPN hub" (whatever that means) which is Linksys model BEFSX41 and I suspect I maybe able to connect everything using this hub but am not sure how to configure it. Here is my planned topology:

[image]

The fourth port on the BEFSX41 is labeled "DMZ", I have no idea why. However, the router promises the ability to "daisy chain out to more hubs", so I assume that the "daisy chain" goes out from the "DMZ" port.

Will this even work, and if it will I have two questions:

(1) What is a VPN hub and why is it useful for a situation like this?

(2) How do I configure the BEFSX41?

(3) How do I tell the computers where to find the printer once it is configured (computers are Linux, Windows XP, and Windows 8)?